# Change UITableView position if UISearchBar is clicked: [using ModernSearchBar]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Swift and come from a non developer background - so do bear with me while I explain the issue. I'm using Swift 4, Xcode 9

I needed an auto suggest feature on a `UISearchBar` I'm using within my app - for which I've used the [ModernSearchBar](https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/ModernSearchBar) library. It's been working fine for me, but recently I edited my `UISearchBar` code so that it moves to the top of the page and a larger area is available for users to see suggestions within. But I'm currently facing [this issue](https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/ModernSearchBar/issues/23) - so while the `UISearchBar` goes up as expected the suggestions list does not. I know this problem is very specific to this library but I would greatly appreciate it if someone pointed me in the right direction on this.

ModernSearchBar itself is a pretty neat addition to the app otherwise and I would like to retain it if possible. But do let me know if I should consider moving away from it and build the UI out myself.

Comment: when click on search bar you have to change constraint of top of tableview.

Comment: So I noticed something while editing the library. If I tap inside the `UISearchBar` once (then it moves up) and then tap outside of it once and then again inside (the `UISearchBar` is still at the top) - the position for the `UITableView` updates by itself. So the position shift of the `UISearchBar` is not detected the first time but it is on the second tap. Maybe I should look into the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` function?

Comment: are working Constraints base?If yes then you need to set layOutIfNeeded() for parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found a relatively easy solution - the file `ModernSearchBar.swift` in the library has a function called `configureViews()` that sets the attributes of the `UITableView` (which is the the suggestions list). I edited the `searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)` function and added this line `if self.suggestionsView.frame.height == 0.0 { self.configureViews() }` to it. This worked, ie, the suggestions list view also got updated to the `UISearchBar`'s top position as expected. And it also does not update the position multiple times because of the frame height constraint.

**Update:**
Another issue I ran into was that if I searched for a word and returned to the previous page, the search results view would move up slightly every time and started covering the `UISearchBar` section and then went out of the view. The problem got solved after I removed the code to update suggestion list size in `keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)` function in the same file. Not sure about the reason for this but now it works fine on the phone as well as simulator.